# React: "Module not found: Can't resolve" Path error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code in my **src/components**:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import Typography from 'Typography';
```

I have one file named Typography.js in the **same directory**.

I have two Ubuntu systems.  In one system, this code is working fine, and in the other, it gives this error on line 3:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'Typography'

If I use `import Typography from './Typography';` then it won't give me the error, but why does the same code work on one system but not the other?

Should I have used `import Typography from './Typography';` everywhere?

here is my 
**webpack-config**

```
resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      'babel-runtime': path.dirname(
        require.resolve('babel-runtime/package.json')
      ),
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  }
```

Comment: Is default export or export? Where you have Typography located?

Comment: export and in same directory where my main file located.

Comment: Got the same problem 2 days back but didn't found solution

Comment: If you're down voting the question the mention the reason as well.Else I don't understand the reason. If you think that this is silly or not so hard question then give answer with proper explanation.

Comment: Are you, by chance, using webpack in your project? If yes, can you share with us the config file of webpack, especially `resolve` option

Comment: check updated question @blaz

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when trying to use a front end template, in which they always use

```
import Typography from 'Typography';
```

instead of the relative path:

```
import Typography from './Typography'
```

And the template actually works in one laptop, and not the other.

And it seems to have something to do with the environment variable `NODE_PATH`, some how it is different between laptops, I am not sure why.

So, my quick fix here is to create a file named `.env` in the same folder as `package.json`, with this one line `NODE_PATH=./src`, this will helps setting `NODE_PATH` to `./src` value.

Err, hope you still need the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since the file is in same directory

If it’s not default export You should import it like

```
  import { Typography} from './Typography';
```

If default export, you should import it like

```
 import Typography from './Typography';
```

Comment: But why I do that? In one system code is working fine without error. I dont want to do **./** in every file.

Comment: That refers to current directory. You have to do my brother it’s not a library but it’s your custom file. That’s how you import your files. That’s very basic thing we all aware about

Comment: I know that, I also wrote in question that If I follow that way then I got no error. But If that was the actual problem then in none system that code runs as far as my knowledge. If code is running in one system and gives the error in another one then there might be environment problem not a code problem. Hope you understand that.

Answer (score 0):

> `Module not found: Can't resolve <module name> in <file path>`

I ran

```
npm install
npm build
npm start
```

Now the module has been installed under `dependencies` in `package.json`, and my web app starts in `http://localhost:3000/`, the port specified in `launch.json`.

Comment: OP asked for importing local directory, not npm packages located in `node_modules` folder, so I believe this answer doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @blaz exactly. This is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules

> resolve.modules [string]: ['node_modules']
>
> Tell webpack what directories should be searched when resolving
>   modules.
>
> Absolute and relative paths can both be used, but be aware that they
>   will behave a bit differently.
>
> A relative path will be scanned similarly to how Node scans for
>   node_modules, by looking through the current directory as well as its
>   ancestors (i.e. ./node_modules, ../node_modules, and on).
>
> With an absolute path, it will only search in the given directory.

webpack's `resolve.modules` is an array containing paths that webpack will use to resolve directory in your code. So, if you use:

```
import Typography from 'Typography';
```

the array in `resolve.modules` should contain `src/components` or any equivalent so that webpack knows where to look for folder Typography. You can try to look into that configuration part to see if the same path is there.

Answer (score 0):

For me, react was importing using relative paths.

For my project, i made the src folder the go to folder.

**create a jsconfig.json file in your root dir(where package.json is located) and add this:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

**Also create an .env or .env.template file in the project's root dir(where package.json is located) if none exist, and add**

```
NODE_PATH=src
// and if this does not work try
NODE_PATH=./src
```

This should allow react to compile.